# Vue 3 compoition API computed function

Tags: vuejs3

Trying to switch my code to the new composition API that comes with Vue 3 but I cant get it to work.

```
export default {
    props: {
       classProp: {type: String},
       error: {type: String},            
    },
    setup(){
     
        // move to here (this is not working)
        computed(() => {
          const classObject = () => {
            return ['form__control', this.classProp, 
                {              
                    'form__invalid': this.error
                }
            ]
          }
        })
    },
    computed: {
         classObject: function () {
             return ['form__control', this.classProp, 
                 {              
                     'form__invalid': this.error
                 }
             ]
         }
    },
}
```

Comment: Please go through the docs again. [You should avoid using `this` inside `setup` as it won't refer to the component instance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#basics-of-composition-api).

Answer (score 0):

skip "computed" all together
you need to use "ref" or "reactive". these are modules:

```
<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    setup(){
     const whateverObject = ref({ prop: "whatever initial value" });
     whateverObject.value.prop= "if you change something within setup you need to access it trough .value";
     return { whateverObject } // expose it to the template by returning it
    }
</script>
```

if you want to use classes you import them like in this example of my own:

```
import { APIBroker } from '~/helpers/APIbroker'
const api = new APIBroker({})
```

Now "api" can be used inside setup() or wherever